# Images only render when the element is inspected

Tags: javascript, html, image-compression, web-inspector, lossless-compression

I am trying to use javascript to populate Swiper JS slides using JavaScript. However, only the first image seems to load and the other only load when I inspect the page. I've tried to remove any occurrences of the "hidden" class (based on answers to similar questions), doesn't seem to help.

Here's the code:

```
 <div class="py-1 swiper-container">
   <div id='slides' class="swiper-wrapper">
       <!-- Slides -->                      
   </div>
  ...
```

and the JS code injecting the images is:

```
       for (i = 0; i < media_urls.length; i++) {
          var st = '<div class="swiper-slide"> <img src='
          var end = ' class="h-56 rounded-xl object-cover w-full" /></div>'
          mediaHtml += (st + media_urls[i] + end);
        }
        slides.innerHTML = mediaHtml
```

The images load(from an external URL) and seems like this issue is the image file size. How could I compress the image files obtained from their respective URL'x?

Answer (score 0):

Try using your browser's network tool and check if the images actually load or not ... As it is a slider, the other divs may be hidden because your parent div has overflow: hidden, and not because they have display: none.

Comment: It seems that the issue is with the image file size causing them to take long to load. Any thoughts on the best way to compress image file (obtained by their URL)? Also updated the question to clarify this.

Comment: @L887 You can encode image data in a URL, like this: data:image/gif;base64,YourBase64EncodedImageData

Comment: I am looking to compress the image file, can this be achieved by simply altering the encoding of the file?

Comment: Well, using an encoding on the image will save loading time, as the browser will not need to make http requests to fetch the image, it will only interpret the bytes encoded in the url and render the image.